# Member and structs in Lisp

Tags: struct, lisp, common-lisp, member

I know how to check if an item is in a list: `(when (member item list :test #'equalp))`. If I have a list of structs book :

```
(defstruct book
  name
  author
  )
```

how do I check if a book from a certain author is a member of the list (independently of the name)? I know this is a very beginner question and I did try to find the answer by myself but did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`:key` argument](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_.htm):

```
(find author library :test #'string= :key #'book-author)
```

Same with [`member`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mem_m.htm):

```
(member (book-name my-book) library :test #'string= :key #'book-name)
```

Note that `:key` is not called on the `item`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Supposing I want to use the `member`, instead of `find`. Would it be something like `(member book1 library :test #'equalp :key #'book-author)`? (supposing I want to know if a book with the same author as book1 is in the library.